# How to install fiona 1.6?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, fiona

I am trying to install `fiona=1.6` but I get the following error

```
conda install fiona=1.6
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: - 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - conda-forge/noarch::flask-cors==3.0.7=py_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::blaze==0.11.3=py36_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::flask==1.0.2=py_2
failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - fiona=1.6 -> gdal==1.11.4

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org
```

If I try to install `gdal==1.11.4`, I get the following

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal=1.11.4

WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: | 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - conda-forge/noarch::flask-cors==3.0.7=py_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::blaze==0.11.3=py36_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::flask==1.0.2=py_2
failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - gdal=1.11.4

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

This is the result of `conda info`

```
conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : /anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/massaro/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/massaro/.condarc
          conda version : 4.6.11
    conda-build version : 3.17.8
         python version : 3.6.8.final.0
       base environment : /anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : /anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/massaro/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/massaro/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.11 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.6.8 Darwin/17.5.0 OSX/10.13.4
                UID:GID : 502:20
             netrc file : None
```

Comment: Why do you have `defaults` removed from your channels? Conda Forge is not meant to be a self-sufficient channel.

Answer (score 0):

## Python Versions

The [Conda Forge channel only has gdal v1.11.4 for Python 2.7, 3.4, and 3.5](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdal/files?version=1.11.4). You either need to use a newer version of Fiona (current is 1.8) or make a new env that includes one of those older Python versions.

For example,

```
conda create -n fiona_1_6 fiona=1.6 python=3.5
```

## Channel `defaults` is Required

Another issue you face is that you have removed the `defaults` channel from your configuration (as per your `conda info`). It is impossible to install `fiona=1.6` with only the `conda-forge` channel.  My recommendation would be to have both `conda-forge` and `defaults` in your configuration, but just set `conda-forge` to have higher priority (if that's what you want).  You can do this like so,

```
conda config --append channels defaults
```

If you really don't want to include `defaults`, but just want a temporary workaround, then you can simply run the first command with a `--channels | -c` flag

```
conda create -n fiona_1_6 -c conda-forge -c defaults fiona=1.6 python=3.5
```

This will still give `conda-forge` precedence, but allow missing dependencies to be sourced from `defaults`.

## Environment File

If you have more than just Fiona that you require, it may be cleaner to put together a requirements file, like so

#### fiona_1_6.yaml

```
name: fiona_1_6
channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
dependencies:
 - python=3.5
 - fiona=1.6
 - osmnx
```

Then create the new environment with this:

```
conda env create -f fiona_1_6.yaml
```

Comment: @emax please add the output of `conda info` to your question then, because this works for me on OSX.

Comment: just added. The problem is that everything worked fine until I installed the `osmnx` package. It seems that there is a coflinct with the `libgdal` version

Comment: @emax, thanks. Now I can see your underlying issue and have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Doing what the error message told me to,

> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
>   looking for, navigate to https://anaconda.org

and typing in `gdal` in the search box led me to https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdal which has this installation instruction:

> `conda install -c conda-forge gdal=1.11.4`

Try that to install the `gdal` dependency, maybe?

Comment: OP clearly shows `conda-forge` in the channels, so this is not useful. (To be clear, this includes before they edited).